# What is the windows equivalent of Linux command wc -l?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, cmd

I have a piece of code that is meant to send the following to the linux command line:

> wc -l C:/inputdirectory/P*

However, I need to run this script in Windows, and am trying to find the equivalent command. I have tried

> find /c /v C:/inputdirectory/P*

But this throws an error, that /v is not a valid command. Can you please tell me why this isn't working?

*note, the command itself doesn't say "inputdirectory", it has the correct directory, it's just too tedious and private to type out

Comment: Try searching for `""`, i.e. an empty string; use only *backslash* as the path separator; and quote the path if it has spaces in it: `find /c /v "" "C:\inputdirectory\P*"`.

Comment: [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) provides a lot of Linux utilities ported to Windows. ["Get that Linux feeling - on Windows"](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: If you're on Win10, you have WSL with all the Linux goodies

Comment: A good answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54893466/447901

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courtesy of [Eryk Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryk-sun):

Try searching for `""`, i.e. an empty string; use only backslash as the path separator; and quote the path if it has spaces in it:

```
find /c /v "" "C:\inputdirectory\P*"
```

Comment: `FIND /C /V` is not totally equivalent of `wc -l`. It emits a string of dashes followed by the file name, then the count. `---------- README.TXT: 41` Whereas, `wc -l` only emits the count.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Note: If all you need is the line count of a *single* input file, a simple solution (which loads the whole file into memory) is, e.g., `(gc file.txt).Count` (`gc` is a built-in alias for `Get-Content`).

Faster version: `(gc -ReadCount 0 file.txt).Count`</sup>

**From `cmd.exe`** (the Command Prompt / a **batch file**), which is **obsolescent**:

- Use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976811/45375).

**From *PowerShell***, you have **two options**:

- **Option A (*suboptimal*)**: **Use the accepted answer too**, with a small tweak:

```
find --% /c /v "" "C:\inputdirectory\P*"
```

Note: `--%`, the stop-parsing symbol, tells PowerShell to pass subsequent arguments through as-is to the target program (after expanding `cmd`-style environment-variable references such as `%USERNAME%`, if any).

In the case at hand, this prevents PowerShell from parsing `""` and - [mistakenly](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3049) - *neglecting to pass it through* to the external target program (`find.exe`).

For a summary of PowerShell's highly problematic handling of quotes when calling external programs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375).

Output from the above `find.exe` command - and, indeed, any *external program*, is just *text*, and in this case it looks something like this:

```
---------- PFILE1.TXT: 42

---------- PFILE2.TXT: 666

...
```

While this **output is easy to grasp *for a human observer*, it makes subsequent *programmatic* processing cumbersome**, because text parsing is required.

Using a PowerShell-native command (cmdlet), as described below, offers more flexibility, because PowerShell commands typically emit *objects* with *typed properties*, which greatly facilitates subsequent processing.

---

- **Option B (*preferred*)**: **Use PowerShell's own [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) cmdlet with the `-Line` switch:**

Note: While this command is **more verbose** than the `find` solution, it ultimately **offers more flexibility due to outputting *objects* with *typed properties*, which greatly facilitates subsequent processing**; additionally, PowerShell's sophisticated output-formatting system offers user-friendly default representations.

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\inputdirectory\P*" -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content -LiteralPath $file |
    Measure-Object -Line |
      Select-Object @{ Name='File'; Expression={ $file } }, Lines
}
```

The above **outputs *objects* that have a `.File` and `.Lines` property each**, which PowerShell prints as follows by default:

```
File                         Lines
----                         -----
C:\inputdirectory\Pfile1.txt    42
C:\inputdirectory\Pfile2.txt   666
...
```

**In addition to a nicer *presentation* of the output, the object-oriented nature of the output makes it easy to *programmatically process* the results.**

For instance, if you wanted to limit the output to those files whose line count is `100` or greater, pipe to the following [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call to the above command:

```
... | Where-Object Lines -ge 100
```

If you (additionally) wanted to sort by highest line count first, pipe to the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) cmdlet:

```
... | Sort-Object -Descending Lines
```

Comment: The verbose part of this answer is gross. A more streamlined way is described at https://superuser.com/questions/959036/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wc-l tl/dr:  `cat file.txt | Measure-Object -line`

Comment: @MarkHu, all your command does is (a) replace `Get-Content` with its `cat` alias (on Windows), (b) apply `Measure-Object -Line` to a _single_ input file, and (b) without producing the output that `wc -l` would. In other words: you're answering a different, much simpler question, and it's no surprise that the solution is shorter. If all you're interested in is knowing a _single_ file's _line count_, use `(cat file.txt).Count`

Comment: @MarkHu, as for the `(ls | Measure-Object -line).Lines` shown in the linked SU post:   just use `(gci).Count` - no need for `Measure-Object` at all. (`gci` is a built-in alias of `Get-ChildItem`, as is `ls` on _Windows_; however, on Unix-like platforms, `ls` refers to the external `/bin/ls` utility).

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I count the lines in a set of files?

Use the following batch file (CountLines.cmd):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b %1`)  do (
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`type %%a ^| find "" /v /c`) do (
    set /a lines += %%b
    )
  )
echo %lines%
endlocal
```

Usage:

```
CountLines C:/inputdirectory/P*
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, if we `type` the file through a pipe to `find`, there's no filename for a summary header, so `find` just outputs the line count. The inner `for /f` 'loop' extracts this result and, in this case, adds it to the running total lines for all processed files.

Comment: This is an interesting exercise in reporting the _total_ line count, _summed_ across multiple files, but that's _not_ what `wc -l C:/inputdirectory/P*` does; the latter reports the count _per input file_ in the form `<count> <file>`, which is also what `find.exe` does _directly_ when file arguments are passed, differences in formatting details aside.