# Powershell Count lines extremely large file

Tags: performance, powershell

I have a extremely large text file of size 250 GB that's given to us by a vendor. They also give us a control file that is supposed to have the number of lines in the large file. Sometimes there is a mismatch.
   How do I count lines in Powershell? I tried this command and it ran for more than half hour and was not done yet.

```
Get-content C:\test.txt | Measure-Object –Line

(gc C:\test.txt | Measure-object | select count).count
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
MR

Comment: Thanks, @phuclv - My comment - since removed - was meant for a different post which has now been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If performance matters, avoid the use of cmdlets and the pipeline; use [`switch -File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6):

```
$count = 0
switch -File C:\test.txt { default { ++$count } }
```

`switch -File` enumerates the lines of the specified file; condition `default` matches any line.

---

To give a sense of the performance difference:

```
# Create a sample file with 100,000 lines.
1..1e5 > tmp.txt
# Warm up the file cache
foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines("$pwd/tmp.txt")) { }

(Measure-Command { (Get-Content tmp.txt | Measure-Object).Count }).TotalSeconds

(Measure-Command { $count = 0; switch -File tmp.txt { default { ++$count } } }).TotalSeconds
```

Sample results from my Windows 10 / PSv5.1 machine:

```
1.3081307  # Get-Content + Measure-Object
0.1097513  # switch -File
```

That is, on my machine the `switch -File` command was about 12 times faster.

Comment: Can this be used to count the number of CRLF in a large file? I've asked a question here and received a solution which works for smaller `.txt` files but runs out of memory for large ones - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65813430/6900402

Comment: @Chipmunk_da, as with `Get-Content`, `switch -File` splits lines on `CRLF` but ***also*** on `CR` and `LF`, therefore this answer can't be used in your specific situation. See my answer on your original question: [Powershell - Count number of carriage returns line feed in .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814922/1701026) for something that might work for you.

Answer (score 11):

## The File

I have a 1.39 GB csv file:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         10/4/2021   1:23 PM     1397998768 XBTUSD.csv
```

## WSL - through NTFS

`wc -l` in WSL. Accessing file via `/mnt/c/Users`.

Slower because file is on the NTFS side.

```
$ time wc -l XBTUSD.csv
41695261 XBTUSD.csv

real    0m10.935s
user    0m0.951s
sys     0m1.427s
```

## WSL - file on Linux side.

`wc -l` in WSL. File is in `/tmp`.

```
time wc -l /tmp/XBTUSD.csv
41695261 /tmp/XBTUSD.csv

real    0m0.447s
user    0m0.258s
sys     0m0.189s
```

## Standard PowerShell approach

`Measure-Command { Get-Content .\XBTUSD.csv | Measure-Object -Line }`

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 7
Seconds           : 52
Milliseconds      : 353
Ticks             : 4723537381
TotalDays         : 0.00546705715393518
TotalHours        : 0.131209371694444
TotalMinutes      : 7.87256230166667
TotalSeconds      : 472.3537381
TotalMilliseconds : 472353.7381
```

## Using LINQ methods in PowerShell: `ReadLines` and `Count`

```
Measure-Command {
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Count(
        [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((ls .\XBTUSD.csv).FullName)) 
}
```

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 7
Milliseconds      : 263
Ticks             : 72636842
TotalDays         : 8.40704189814815E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00201769005555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.121061403333333
TotalSeconds      : 7.2636842
TotalMilliseconds : 7263.6842
```

## Switch in PowerShell

```
Measure-Command { 
    $count = 0; switch -File .\XBTUSD.csv { default { ++$count } }; $count 
}
```

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 44
Milliseconds      : 975
Ticks             : 449752555
TotalDays         : 0.000520546938657407
TotalHours        : 0.0124931265277778
TotalMinutes      : 0.749587591666667
TotalSeconds      : 44.9752555
TotalMilliseconds : 44975.2555
```

## Summary

- Fastest is `wc -l` in WSL.
- Fastest in PowerShell is the LINQ methods

Answer (score 6):

For such a huge file I'd rather go with some C written utility. Install gitbash, it should have wc command:

```
wc -l yourfile.txt
```

I tested it on 5GB/50M line file (on HDD), it took about 40s. The best powershell solution took about 2 minutes.  You also may check your file, it might have some auto incremental indexes or constant row size.

Comment: Confirmed that this is far faster (took a few seconds vs >5 minutes) than "switch -File" in Powershell for a 9 GB file using Git Bash.  I could download, install, and run it before "switch -File" would even be done.