# Powershell - Count number of carriage returns line feed in .txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a large text file (output from SQL db) and I need to determine the row count. However, since the source SQL data itself contains carriage returns `\r` and line feeds `\n` (NEVER appearing together), the data for some rows spans multiple lines in the output .txt file. The Powershell I'm using below gives me the file line count which is greater than the actual SQL row count. So I need to modify the script to ignore the additional lines - one way of doing it might be just counting the number of times `CRLF` or `\r\n` occurs (TOGETHER) in the file and that should be the actual number of rows but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
Get-ChildItem "." |% {$n = $_; $c = 0; Get-Content -Path $_ -ReadCount 1000 |% { $c += $_.Count }; "$n; $c"} > row_count.txt
```

Comment: Something like `[regex]::Matches((Get-Content file.txt -Raw),'\r\n').Count` should work.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks! I'll try this out now

Comment: This works perfectly..the only issue is that I get an out of memory exception since the file is 12gb. Is there a way to avoid that? Maybe like reading a few thousand lines at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just learned myself that the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) splits and streams each lines in a file by `CR`, `CRLF`, and `LF` sothat it can read data between operating systems interchangeably:

```
"1`r2`n3`r`n4" | Out-File .\Test.txt
(Get-Content .\Test.txt).Count
4
```

Reading the question again, I might have misunderstood your question.
In any case, if you want to split (count) on only a specific character combination:

#### CR

```
((Get-Content -Raw .\Test.txt).Trim() -Split '\r').Count
3
```

#### LF

```
((Get-Content -Raw .\Test.txt).Trim() -Split '\n').Count
3
```

#### CRLF

```
((Get-Content -Raw .\Test.txt).Trim() -Split '\r\n').Count # or: -Split [Environment]::NewLine
2
```

Note `.Trim()` method which removes the extra newline (white spaces) at the end of the file added by the `Get-Content -Raw` parameter.

---

#### Addendum

<sup>(Update based on the comment on the memory exception)</sup>
I am afraid that there is currently no other option then building your own [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) using the [ReadBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readblock) method and specifically split lines on a CRLF. I have opened a feature request for this issue: [-NewLine Parameter to customize line separator for Get-Content](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14647)

#### Get-Lines

A possible way to workaround the memory exception errors:

```
function Get-Lines {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([string])] param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True)][string] $Filename,
        [String] $NewLine = [Environment]::NewLine
    )
    Begin {
        [Char[]] $Buffer = new-object Char[] 10
        $Reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList (Get-Item($Filename))
        $Rest = '' # Note that a multiple character newline (as CRLF) could be split at the end of the buffer
    }
    Process {
       While ($True) {
            $Length = $Reader.ReadBlock($Buffer, 0, $Buffer.Length)
            if (!$length) { Break }
            $Split = ($Rest + [string]::new($Buffer[0..($Length - 1)])) -Split $NewLine
            If ($Split.Count -gt 1) { $Split[0..($Split.Count - 2)] }
            $Rest = $Split[-1]
        }
    }
    End {
        $Rest
    }
}
```

#### Usage

To prevent the memory exceptions it is important that you do not assign the results to a variable or use brackets as this will stall the PowerShell PowerShell pipeline and store everything in memory.

```
$Count = 0
Get-Lines .\Test.txt | ForEach-Object { $Count++ }
$Count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried `((Get-Content -Raw .\Test.txt).Trim() -Split '\r\n').Count`. The only issue is that I get an out of memory exception since the file is 12gb. Is there a way to avoid that? Maybe like reading a few thousand lines at a time?

Comment: Thanks for this @iRon! I'll upvote that request!

Comment: Nicely done on the `System.IO.StreamReader` solution; note that you can speed up with `[string]::new($Buffer[0..($Length - 1)])`, which is much faster than unary `-join`. As for the pure PowerShell solution: note that `Get-Content` has a `-Delimiter` parameter, which can be used here (see my answer).

Comment: Great, thanks for this @iRon!. I tested it on a smalled file first, and looks like it does take slightly longer than your previous answer, but produced the count correctly! I'll try it out on the larger file now.

Comment: qq- Can I use `Trim()` on this as well to get rid of the extra CRLF? So, I can change it to `(Get-Lines .\Test.txt).Trim()`?

Comment: There shouldn't be any `CRLF` left in the returned strings. Note that the function returns a stream (collection) of strings (`string[]`). Anyways, the solution from @mklement0 probably better (at least easier). I completely missed the `-Delimiter` parameter of the `Get-Content` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

- The [`System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBlock) solution that reads the file in fixed-size blocks and performs custom splitting into lines in [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814922/45375) is the best choice, because it both avoids out-of-memory problems and performs well (by PowerShell standards).
- If performance in terms of execution speed isn't paramount, you can take advantage of
  **[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Delimiter` parameter**, which accepts a custom string to split the file content by:

```
# Outputs the count of CRLF-terminated lines.
(Get-Content largeFile.txt -Delimiter "`r`n" | Measure-Object).Count
```

---

Note that **`-Delimiter` employs *optional-terminator* logic** when splitting: that is, if the file content *ends in* the given delimiter string, *no* extra, empty element is reported at the end.

This is consistent with the default behavior, where a trailing newline in a file is considered an optional terminator that does *not* resulting in an additional, empty line getting reported.

However, in case a `-Delimiter` string that is *unrelated to newline characters* is used, a trailing newline *is* considered a final "line" (element).

A quick example:

```
# Create a test file without a trailing newline.
# Note the CR-only newline (`r) after 'line 1'
"line1`rrest of line1`r`nline2" | Set-Content -NoNewLine test1.txt

# Create another test file with the same content plus 
# a trailing CRLF newline.
"line1`rrest of line1`r`nline2`r`n" | Set-Content -NoNewLine test2.txt

'test1.txt', 'test2.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  "--- $_"
  # Split by CRLF only and enclose the resulting lines in [...]
  Get-Content $_ -Delimiter "`r`n" | 
    ForEach-Object { "[{0}]" -f ($_ -replace "`r", '`r') }
}
```

This yields:

```
--- test1.txt
[line1`rrest of line1]
[line2]
--- test2.txt
[line1`rrest of line1]
[line2]
```

As you can see, the two test files were processed identically, because the trailing CRLF newline was considered an optional terminator for the last line.

Comment: Thanks! But this would run into memory issues?

Comment: Sometimes this method produces `<NumberOfCRLF>+1` if the final line does not actually contain a `CRLF`.

Comment: @Chipmunk_da: No, the command uses the pipeline's streaming behavior, so the lines are read one at a time. You would only run into trouble if you had individual CRLF lines that themselves are multiple gigabytes, which seems unlikely.

Comment: @AdminOfThings: The command counts the number of _lines_, not the number of CRLF sequences, because the trailing CRLF sequence is considered an _optional terminator_, not a _separator_ - please see my update.