# 'kubectl patch' works on Linux Bash but not in Windows Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing, kubectl, quoting

The following command works fine on Ubuntu bash:

```
kubectl patch deployment wapi-backend-d1 --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"metadata": {"labels": {"date": "test"}}}}}'
```

The same command does not work in Windows Powershell Console (ISE).

The error is:

```
kubectl : Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string
At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl patch deployment wapi-backend-d1 --patch '{"spec": {"template ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error from serv...ject key string:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

The powershell console version is:

```
PS > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I have tried the command with a different patched value too as I saw somebody write that patch may fail if it is already applied.

The path /spec/template/metadata/labels/date indeed exists in the deployment's yaml, so that isn't a problem either.

I presume that it might have something to do with kubectl working differently in Powershell in relation to quotes, but could not find a way to make it work.

I have tried

```
kubectl patch deployment wapi-backend-d1 --patch "{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"metadata\": {\"labels\": {\"date\": \"test123\"}}}}}"
```

But that results in

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "spec\\: {\\template\\: {\\metadata\\: {\\labels\\: {\\date\\: \\test123\\}}}}}" not found
```

What should be the command on Powershell?

Comment: Can you get the json from a file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For detailed and very useful background, see the [answer by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/1246369)

After much frustration, I have decided to list all variants of quote escaping that I've tried, and came up with one more, which suddenly worked!
So, sharing it here:

```
kubectl patch deployment wapi-backend-d1 --patch '{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"metadata\": {\"labels\": {\"date\": \"test123\"}}}}}'
```

This is how to use kubectl patch with Powershell

Also, of note: I was actually trying to patch it with a timestamp to trigger a rolling update without changing tags of container images (so set image would not help me).

When you try to put your JSON into a variable and then call kubectl patch with a variable, you get into trouble with escaping again. This is what I ended up with:

```
$patchRequest = @{
    spec = @{
        template = @{
            metadata = @{
                labels = @{
                    date = ((((Get-Date -Format o)).replace(':','-').replace('+','_')))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$patchJson = ((ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $patchRequest -Compress -Depth 10))
$patchJson = $patchJson.replace('"','\"')
kubectl patch deployment wapi-backend-d1 --patch $patchJson
```

Answer (score 10):

You've found the right solution in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602560/45375), but let me try to break it down conceptually:

##### Embedding `"` (double quotes) in string arguments passed to external programs:

- (a) First - sensibly and unavoidably - you need to satisfy *PowerShell*'s syntax requirements with respect to embedding `"` chars. in quoted strings.
- (b) **Then - and this step shouldn't be necessary - you need to `\`-escape embedded `"` chars. that you want *external programs* to see**.

  - This is a **longstanding, irksome bug in *Windows PowerShell* and [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.2.x*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) - which  is **fixed in 7.3+, in with selective exceptions on Windows** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

**Re (a)**, you have the following options:

- **`'...'`-quoting (single-quoting)**, i.e. a [***verbatim string***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), inside of which you can use `"` as-is:

  - `'{ "spec": "none" }'`
  - **Everything inside `'...'` is taken *verbatim* (literally)** - no expansion (string interpolation) takes place.
- **`"..."`-quoting (double-quoting)**, i.e. an [***expandable string***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), inside of which you can use `` `" `` or `""` to embed `"` chars:

  - `` "{ `"spec`": `"none`" }" `` - `` ` `` is PowerShell's general escape char.
  - `"{ ""spec"": ""none"" }"` - `"`-specific escaping (doubling)
  - The content of **`"..."` is subject to *expansion* (string interpolation)**, meaning that you **can reference variables (`$var`) or subexpressions (`$(1 + 2)`)** inside such strings, which PowerShell replaces with their values - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for more about PowerShell's *expandable strings*.

If you're **passing such a string to other *PowerShell* commands** (cmdlets, functions, or scripts), **no further action is needed**; e.g.:

```bash
PS> Write-Output '3" of rain'
3" of rain
```

**Re (b)** - i.e. to **pass such strings to *external programs* - you *additionally* need to `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars.**:

- Applying *manual* escaping to the examples above:

  - `'{ \"spec\": \"none\" }'`
  - `` "{ \`"spec\`": \`"none\`" }" ``
  - `"{ \""spec\"": \""none\"" }"`
- Applying the **escaping *programmatically*** to a preexisting string:

  - Replace verbatim `"` with verbatim `\"`, as well as any preexisting, *immediately preceding* `\` with `\\`:

    - `$str = '3" of rain';  $escapedStr = $str -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"'`
    - That is, for an external program to ultimately see value `3" of rain` verbatim, you must pass literal value `3\" of rain` from PowerShell. *This `\`-escaping is something that PowerShell, as a shell, should do automatically behind the scenes, but currently doesn't.*
- There's an **additional bug in *Windows PowerShell*** - since fixed in PowerShell *Core* - that **mishandles strings with *unbalanced* embedded `"` chars. if a `"` is *part of the first word***:

  - E.g., the above techniques do NOT work with literal values such as `3" of rain`; that is, escaping this as `'3\" of rain'` does *not* work as expected - instead, you must use the following monstrosity: `` `"3\`" of rain`" ``, which is technically a series of separate, unquoted arguments, which means that (a) multiple spaces between the words of the strings aren't supported (they are collapsed to a single space) and (b) PowerShell metacharacters such as `& < > $ & | @ {` must be individually `` ` ``-escaped.
  - Note that the bug surfaces only if the `"` is part of the first word in the value, and only if that first word is not preceded by whitespace (though arguments with leading whitespace are rarely useful); e.g., `'3 \" of rain'` would again work, because the unbalanced `"` is not part of the first word.

**Example**:

The following uses `choice.exe` as an example external program, because it can be repurposed (via options `/d Y /t 0`) to merely *echo* the prompt string it is given, which shows how it received the string passed from PowerShell:

```bash
& {
  # Note: For preview versions of v7.2, deactivate the experimental
  #       feature that fixes the problem, so as to show the original problem.   
  $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'

  # Use manual \-escaping to pass what should be received as
  # verbatim { "spec": "none" } to an external program.
  choice /m '{ \"spec\": \"none\" }' /d Y /t 0
}
```

The above outputs `{ "spec": "none" } [Y,N]?Y`, showing that the manually escaped `"` chars. were received as verbatim `"` chars. by the external program.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked
kubectl patch cronjobs address-update-cron-job -p "{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}"