# What is wrong with this Google BigQuery Data Transfer 'bq mk --transfer_config' command's syntax?

Tags: powershell, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk, bq

I am trying to use the `bq` CLI to create a BigQuery Data Transfer Service following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer), but for some reason, when I run this in the PowerShell I keep getting this error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Here is my command

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=ingestion-test --data_source=google_cloud_storage --display_name='DTA' --target_dataset=Data --params='{"data_path_template":"gs://mydata-766451231152/a_*","destination_table_name_template":"alpha","file_format":"CSV","max_bad_records":"0","ignore_unknown_values":"true","field_delimiter":"|","skip_leading_rows":"0","allow_quoted_newlines":"true","allow_jagged_rows":"false","delete_source_files":"false"}' --data_source=google_cloud_storage
```

I have tried all the normal things like escaping double quotes with `\`, `""`, etc. It seems the error is in the `--params` part because without that, the command actually goes through, but obviously fails because `--params` is required. All examples I have seen online show the same syntax.

What is wrong?

Comment: The command you provided works correctly on my end (changing the bucket, dataset and project ID of course). What's the Cloud SDK version you're using (check that with `gcloud info`)? Also you're specifying  `--data_source` twice there - I don't think it's related but I doubt it's needed... I reckon you can remove the last one.

Comment: Also, since you mention it fails when using the PowerShell, does it work when you run it through the Cloud Shell for example? It could be something more related to Windows.

Comment: Is bq a .cmd file?  Can --params be taken from a file?  It looks like json.

Comment: It's PowerShell, unfortunately: sadly, you must manually `\ `-escape the `"` inside your `'...'` string - see the linked post and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375).

Comment: Aah this was frustrating. What finally worked was escaping the | delimiter with ^.

Comment: ^ is a cmd quote symbol.  I suspect that bq is a .bat script.  They should make a .ps1 version.