# Supplying Powershell arguments to 'start' breaks the command?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that calls ffmpeg to do a two-pass encode of all .mp4 video files in the current folder.

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem . | Where { $_.extension -like ".mp4" }) {
  ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -b:v 2.2M -preset medium -x265-params pass=1 -an -f mkv NUL
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -b:v 2.2M -x265-params pass=2 -c:a libopus -ac 1 -b:a 64k -preset medium "small\$i.mkv"
}
```

It works perfectly but brings my system to a halt when in use, so I want to give the ffmpeg processes a low priority and an affinity that only lets them use two CPU cores. So I try

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem . | Where { $_.extension -like ".mp4" }) {
  start "x265ify" /wait /low /b /affinity C ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -b:v 2.1M -preset medium -x265-params pass=1 -an -f mkv NUL
  start "x265ify" /wait /low /b /affinity C ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -b:v 2.1M -x265-params pass=2 -c:a libopus -ac 1 -b:a 64k -preset medium "small\$i.mkv"
}
```

This doesn't work, because the `-i` is considered to be ambiguous. So I try putting the entire command (`"ffmpeg -y -i..."` onward) in a string, with the quotation marks escaped. That doesn't work because a positional parameter can't be found that accepts `/low`. I try omitting that, passing the command as a separate variable, nothing I try seems to work.

Yet I have an Ruby script invoking ffmpeg the exact same way that *does* work. It reads

```
start "x265-ifier" /wait /low /b /affinity #{AFFINITY} ffmpeg \
              -hide_banner \
              -i "#{v}" \
              -vf scale=-2:#{HEIGHT} \
              -c:a libopus \
              -b:a #{AUDIO_BITRATE}k \
              -ac 1 \
              -c:v libx265 \
              -x265-params vbv-maxrate=#{MAX_VIDEO_BITRATE}:vbv-bufsize=7000 \
              -preset #{PRESET} \
              -crf #{CRF} \
              "#{dest}" \
              -y
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why does PowerShell not want to run this command, which runs okay if Ruby is the middleman? Why is `/low` not a parameter when it's listed in the documentation as one, and how can I make `-i` any less ambiguous when the entire string passed to `start` is supposed to be the command it's running, with `-i` as a valid argument of that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, `start` is the built-in alias for the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet<sup>[1]</sup>, whose syntax and behavior differ from the *internal* `start` command of `cmd.exe`.

In order to call the latter<sup>[1]</sup>, you must invoke `cmd.exe` explicitly, as follows:

```
cmd /c start `"x265ify`" /wait /low /b /affinity C ffmpeg -y -i $i -c:v libx265 -b:v 2.1M -preset medium -x265-params pass=1 -an -f mkv NUL
```

Note:

- The `"` chars. around `x265ify` are escaped as `` `" `` to ensure that they're passed through to `start`, which (awkwardly) uses them to distinguish between the first argument representing a *window title* vs. the command to invoke.
- `$i` doesn't have to be double-quoted, because PowerShell will do that on demand.
- Using `/wait` means that your second `start` command won't be invoked until the first one has completed.

As an aside: PowerShell's handling of *empty* arguments (`""`) and arguments with *embedded* `"` chars. passed to *external programs* is fundamentally broken as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0, requiring awkward workarounds - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Use `Get-Command start` to discover this fact.</sup>

<sup>[2] which is necessary in your case, because `Start-Process` doesn't offer control over the launched process' priority or CPU affinity.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it, @GreenTriangle. Please see my update, which describes how to identify a command as an alias, and links to a post with potential problems when passing arguments to external programs.