# Passing Json to Python from PowerShell Script

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

I'm trying without sucess to pass a Json string to a Python Script using PowerShell Script (.ps1) to automate this task.

```
spark-submit `
--driver-memory 8g `
--master local[*] `
--conf spark.driver.bindAddress=127.0.0.1 `
--packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:7.0.0 `
--py-files build/dependencies.zip build/main.py `
$param
```

When `$param='{ \"\"job_start\"\": \"\"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test\"\"}'` works fine, the python receives a valid JSON string and parse correctly.

When I use the character `&` like `$param='{ \"\"job_start\"\": \"\"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false\"\"}'` the string is printed like `{ "job_start": \jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test?` and the rest of the string are reconized as other commands.

```
'serverTimezone' is not recognized as an internal or external command
'autoReconnect' is not recognized as an internal or external command
'useSSL' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

The `\"\"` is need to maintain the double quots in the Python script, not sure why need two escaped double quotes.

**UPDATE:**

Now I'm having problems with the `!` character, I can't escape this character even with `^ or \`.

```
# Only "" doesn't work
$param='{\"\"job_start\"\": \"\"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test^&serverTimezone=UTC\"\", \"\"password\"\": \"\"testpassword^!123\"\"}'

spark-submit.cmd `
--driver-memory 8g `
--master local[*] `
--conf spark.driver.bindAddress=127.0.0.1 `
--packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:7.0.0 `
--py-files build/dependencies.zip build/main.py `
$param

# OUTPUT: misses the ! character
{"job_start": "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test&serverTimezone=UTC", "password": "testpassword123"}
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: I wonder if the spark-submit has another context the a simple python script?

Comment: It would be good to understand whether there truly is a problem with how `spark-submit` relays arguments to Python, or whether the problem is unique to your scenario / environment. Also, in your update you refer to _output_: who produces that output?

Comment: @mklement0 yes I'm trying to figure out what happen with ````spark-submit```, because passing directly to Python is working with yours explanations. About the output is a print function in the begining of my spark script

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Note: The following does *not* solve the OP's specific problem (the cause of which is still unknown), but hopefully contains information of general interest.

```
# Use "" to escape " and - in case of delayed expansion - ^! to escape !
$param = '{ ""job_start"": ""jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test&serverTimezone=UTC&more^!"" }'
```

- There are high-profile utilities (CLIs) such as `az` (Azure) that are *Python*-based, but *on Windows* use an *auxiliary batch file* as the executable that simply relays arguments to a Python script.

  - Use `Get-Command az`, for instance, to discover an executable's full file name; batch files, which are processed by `cmd.exe`, the legacy command processor, have a filename extension of either `.cmd` or `.bat`
- To prevent calls to such a batch file from breaking, double quotes embedded in arguments passed from PowerShell must be escaped as `""`
- Additionally, but *only if* `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect in a given target batch file *or* if your computer is configured to use delayed expansion *by default*, for *all* batch files:

  - `!` characters must be escaped as `^!`, which, however, is only effective if `cmd.exe` considers the `!` part of a double-quoted string.

---

It looks like we have a **confluence of *two* problems**:

- **A *PowerShell* problem with `"` chars. *embedded* in arguments passed to *external programs***:

  - In an ideal world, passing JSON text such as `'{ "foo": "bar" }'` to an *external program* would work *as-is*, but **[due to PowerShell's broken handling of embedded double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375), that is *not* enough, and the `"` chars. must *additionally* be escaped, for the *target* program, either as `\"` (which most programs support), or, in the case of `cmd.exe` (see below), as `""`**, which Python fortunately recognizes too: `'{ ""foo"": ""bar"" }'`
- **Limitations of argument-passing and escaping in `cmd.exe` *batch files***:

  - It sounds like `spark-submit` is an *auxiliary batch file* (`.cmd` or `.bat`) that passes the arguments *through* to a Python script.
  - The problem is that **if you use `\"` for escaping embedded `"`, `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize them as *escaped*, which causes it to consider the `&` characters *unquoted***, and they are therefore interpreted as *shell metacharacters*, i.e. as characters with special syntactic function (command sequencing, in this case).
  - Additionally, and **only if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect** in a given batch file, any **literal `!` characters in arguments** require additional handling:

    - If `cmd.exe` thinks the `!` is part of an *unquoted* argument, you cannot escape `!` at all.
    - Inside a *quoted* argument (which invariably means `"..."` in `cmd.exe`), you must escape a literal `!` as `^!`.

      - Note that this requirement is the *inverse* of how all *other* metacharacters must be escaped (which require `^` when *unquoted*, but not inside `"..."`).
      - The unfortunate consequence is that **you need to know the *implementation details* of the target batch file - whether it uses `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or not - in order to formulate your arguments properly.**
      - The **same applies if your computer is configured to use delayed expansion *by default***, for *all* batch files (and interactively), which is neither common nor advisable. To test if a given computer is configured that way, check the output from the following command for `DelayedExpansion : 1`: if there's no output at all, delayed expansion is OFF; if there's 1 or 2 outputs, delayed expansion is ON by default if the *first or only* output reports `DelayedExpansion : 1`.

```
 Get-ItemProperty -EA Ignore 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor', 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor' DelayedExpansion
```

---

**Workaround**:

- Since you're technically calling a batch file, use `""` to escape literal `"` chars. inside your single-quoted (`'...'`) PowerShell string.
- If you know that the target batch file uses `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` *or* if your computer is configured to use delayed expansion *by default*, escape `!` characters as `^!`

  - Note that this is only effective if `cmd.exe` considers the `!` part of a double-quoted string.

Therefore (note that I've extended the URL to include a token with `!`, meant to be passed through literally as suffix `more!`):

```
$param = '{ ""job_start"": ""jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test&serverTimezone=UTC&more^!"" }'
```

If you need to escape an *existing* JSON string *programmatically*:

```
# Unescaped JSON string, which in an ideal world you'd be able
# to pass as-is.
$param = '{ "job_start": "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test&serverTimezone=UTC&more!" }'

# Escape the " chars.
$param = $param -replace '"', '""'

# If needed, also escape the ! chars.
$param = $param -replace '!', '^!'
```

---

**Ultimately, both problems should be fixed *at the source*** - but that this is highly unlikely, because it would *break backward compatibility*.

With respect to PowerShell, [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) contains the backstory, technical details, a robust wrapper function to hide the problems, and discussions about how to fix the problem at least on an opt-in basis.

Comment: @BrunoBernardes. (As it turns out, the twice-escaping would not have worked anyway with respect to `!`) There must be something else going on, and you need to determine the chain of calls, and where, specifically, the error occurs. The only thing that is certain is that it is `cmd.exe` that is complaining, i.e. that the error occurs in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

In this question [Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash)
, you will find all the characters that you should escape when passing them as normal characters in the shell, you will also notice that `&` is one of them.

Now I understand that if you tried to escape it, the JSON parser you are using will probably fail to parse the string. So one quick workaround would be to replace the `&` by any other special non-escapable symbol like `@` or `%`, and do a step in your app where you replace it with `&` before parsing. Just make sure that the symbol you will use isn't used in your strings, and won't be used at any time.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I send strings in this JSON that contains others special characters and I will needed to figure out replacement for every one of them

Comment: I manage to escape the ```&``` character using ```^```, so the final test string was ```$param='{\"\"job_start\"\": \"\"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/test^&serverTimezone=UTC\"\"}'```, which I think is not that great, but pacience

Comment: Unfortunately, the question was originally mistagged as `bash`, which isn't involved, judging by the error messages. Instead, it is `cmd.exe` via an _auxiliary batch file_ that relays arguments to a Python script. So, unfortunately, there are _two_ shells involved: PowerShell, which has no problem with the `&`, given that it's inside a quoted string, and `cmd.exe`, which is where the problem manifests. Two general asides: If something is correctly escaped, the escape character is _removed_ during parsing; also, `spark-submit` is a third-party tool, so modifying it isn't really an option.