# Appending strings to output of jsonpath expression when listing pod labels using kubectl

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

I have a json path command to get all the labels of my pods.

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.labels}"
```

This will output:

```
{
    "app": "api-dogs-v1",
    "release": "0.0.119"
} {
    "app": "api-cats-v1",
    "release": "0.0.16"
}
```

I want to do some simple manipulation of the command so that it outputs valid json and surround inside a json object.

I'm trying the below:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{"{"}{{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{"}"}{end}'
```

But this gives me back:

```
unrecognized character in action: U+007B '\'
```

Can anyone help me with this? Desired output below:

```
{
    {
        "app": "api-dogs-v1",
        "release": "0.0.119"
    } {
        "app": "api-cats-v1",
        "release": "0.0.16"
    } 
}
```

thanks!

...........................................

Update

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='"richard"{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{end}"}"'
```

Almost gets me there but I get an error when i change to add curly braces at the start of the json path expression (instead of my name) i believe it thinks i'm starting the function...

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='"{"{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{end}"}"'
```

error: error parsing jsonpath {{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{end}}, unrecognized character in action: U+007B '{'

Comment: I found that you have opened one extra open brace in your command. Kindly recheck the command and try once.

Comment: really bizarre. i've also found that it won't respect my "\n" character when i do this kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{"\n"}{end}. Wondering if this has to do with powershell?

Comment: tried that... so weird... all that does is echo the jsonpath expression back to me

Comment: On Windows, you must double quote any JSONPath template that contains spaces . This in turn means that you must use a single quote or escaped double quote around any literals in the template. For example: `kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{\"\t\"}{.status.startTime}{\"\n\"}{end}"` https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Comment: Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602560/4018180

Answer (score 2):

i have remove extra `{` infront of `{range .items[*]}` and moved `{"}"}` after `{end}` as following :

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{"{"}{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{end}{"}"}'

Output(your desired output format): 
{{"app":"test-multi-pv","pod-template-hash":"55665bc94c"}{"app":"nginx","controller-revision-hash":"web1-774fbdcb49","statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name":"web1-0"}{"app":"nginx","controller-revision-hash":"web2-6b59d76fc6","statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name":"web2-0"}{"app":"nginx","controller-revision-hash":"web3-7c65fbbcdc","statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name":"web3-0"}}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me....error: error parsing jsonpath {{}{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{end}{}}, unrecognized character in action: U+007B '{'

Comment: Maybe it's got to do with escaping characters? I'm using powershell if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have opened one extra open brace in your command. Kindly recheck the command and try once.

I have reproduced the use case and successfully got the expected output.while running the following jsonpath command, I have got all the labels of my pods.

kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.labels}"

Output:

{

"app":"hello-server",
"Pod-template-hash":"5bd6b6875f"

}

I have removed the curly braces of the jsonpath expression “{“ before the {range .items[*]} and added a newline expression before the {end}

So, the final range function for the json object that surrounds the inside json object is

kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{"{"}{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{"}"}{"\n"}{end}'

Expected Output:

{

{

```
 "app":"hello-server",

 "Pod-template-hash":"5bd6b6875f"
```

}

}

Comment: The result I get from the above is .... error: error parsing jsonpath {{}{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels}{}}{\n}{end}, unrecognized character in action: U+007B '{'

Comment: Given you have tested this and is works for you I feel like this might be something specific to powershell?