# Pass a JSON string without using backslashes

Tags: powershell

Using backslashes to pass a JSON string as a parameter in PowerShell is cumbersome.

```
executable --json-input '{ \"name\": \"Bob\" }' output.txt
```

Is there a way to avoid using these backslashes? I tried using single quotes, and doubles quotes in and out without any success. In Python I use triple quotes `print(""" here is an example "" """)` to avoid character escaping.

Is there a similar solution in PowerShell? One where we never need to worry about reformating a JSON string?

Comment: `\"` is not a valid escape sequence in PowerShell - are you perhaps referring to some other shell (bash/zsh/cmd)?

Comment: No, I'm really using PowerShell. It's strange because it really works on my side, here is the full command I use https://pastebin.com/P3pWBNya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The unfortunate need for *manual* `\`-escaping of `"` chars. embedded in string arguments passed to *external programs* is due to a *long-standing PowerShell bug*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) - which is **finally fixed in PowerShell 7.3+, with selective exceptions on Windows** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

- That is to say, **you *should* be able to just pass `'{ "name": "Bob" }'`** - no `\`-escaping, but the bug prevents that.

To ***automate* this escaping for now**, without having to modify a given JSON string, you can apply a regex-based **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation**, namely `$json -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"'`

```bash
# Note: only needed for *external executables*, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x
executable --json-input ('{ "name": "Bob" }' -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"') output.txt
```

Note:

- The above replacement operation also handles *escaped* embedded `"` characters correctly.

  - E.g., `{ "name": "Nat \"King\" Cole" }` becomes 
    `{ \"name\": \"Nat \\\"King\\\" Cole\" }`, with the `\` before `"` properly escaped as `\\`
  - See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/26wt9J/2) for an explanation of the regex and replacement operation (for technical reasons, the linked page uses C#'s string syntax, but the solution is equivalent to what is shown here).
- If you know your JSON input not to contain them, you can simplify to `-replace '"', '\"'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-replace '(["\\])','\$1'`, not `-replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"'`?

Comment: @Mathias, the replacement is designed to _double_ (any non-empty run of) embedded ``\`` chars. that _directly precede a `"`_ in the input string. All other ``\`` instances must be left alone.

Comment: @mklement0 is it here yet?

Comment: @shellwhale, yes, it was fixed in v7.3.0, but with selective exceptions on Windows - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375 for details.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell has [here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings), similar to the multiline literals from Perl (`<<<`) or Python (`"""`).

The starting quote must be preceded by `@` and immediately followed by a line break, whereas the closing quote must follow a newline and be followed by another `@` sign:

```
command --json-input @"
{ "name": "Bob" }
"@ output.txt
```

Comment: I edited my question, could you edit your answer too? I added a mandatory argument, how do you handle new lines in that case?

Comment: Your solution answers my question, but I realized that my issue isn't specific to PowerShell. It's specific to the AWS CLI.

Comment: While here-strings are a helpful pointer in general, note that use of regular single-quoted strings too doesn't require escaping `"` characters; e.g., `'{ "name": "Bob" }`. The need for ``\`` escaping embedded `"` chars. only arises to work around PowerShell's broken argument-passing to _external programs_ up to at least 7.2.x, and it applies whether or not you use here-strings.