# What's Windows' NATIVE version of wc -l filename?

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I count lines of files in Windows in the fastest way, without installing any additional software? Basically, only the equivalent of Windows' `wc -l filename` will do. So no installation of cygwin etc, because I need this to work with installation of other software.

It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976223/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-linux-command-wc-l) as that talks about a solution that I can't re-use as it was designed for multiple files..

Comment: I don't know if there is a faster way, but in PowerShell you could do `(Get-Content 'D:\textfile.txt').Count` or make use of .NET `([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines('D:\textfile.txt')).Count`

Comment: In CMD we can combine the builtin `type` command with find.exe: `type filename | find /c /v ""`. Sending the file contents through a pipe cause `find` to omit the summary and just output the line count from the `/c` option. The `/v` option inverts the match on the empty string `""`, so it matches any line.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question can also be used with a single file. @ErykSun's comment shows a variant that doesn't print the filename.

Answer (score 3):

Measure-Object.  (There are -word and -character options too.)  "type" or "cat" may be an alias for "get-content".

```
get-content filename | Measure-Object -line
```

output

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
    3
```